# Better source and more recent documentation for zc.buildout?

Tags: python, django, buildout

I'm trying to use zc.buildout on a new Django project.  I really like the idea behind the tool and certainly appreciate the effort put into the tool.  I am surprised though at the lack of documentation.  I've listed what I think are the best sources of info about or closely related to buildout.  Are there any better and more recent sources on the syntax of the buildout .cfg file and the use of the tool?

http://www.buildout.org/

http://archlinux.me/dusty/2010/06/17/converting-a-django-project-for-zc-buildout/

http://ircubic.net/2009/11/portable-django-project-with-buildout.html

http://slacy.com/blog/2010/10/both-production-development-settings-using-zc-buildout-djangorecipe/

http://andre.engelbrechtonline.net/blog/2010/03/10/how-i-deploy-django-buildout/

http://ontwik.com/python/django-deployment-workshop-by-jacob-kaplan-moss/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pounding on buildout for a few days I think I understand its workings.  Really, the key is to understand the recipes that buildout uses more than anything else -- a realization that really didn't dawn on me until after I posted this question.